# While i am running my emulator on android studio i frequently get this error and them the system starts restarting

Tags: android-studio, emulation

Emulator: emulator: WARNING: System.cpp:1139: Ignoring invalid parameter detected in function: 0000000000000000 file: 0000000000000000, line: 0, expression: 0000000000000000

Answer (score 2):

got the same Error message....

Emulator: emulator: WARNING: System.cpp:1142: Ignoring invalid parameter detected in function: 0000000000000000 file: 0000000000000000, line: 0, expression: 0000000000000000

Solved it by going into Tools>AVD Manager, selecting the device emulator I was working with and doing wipe data.